# reloadData not working for UITableView inside another UITableView Static Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking, reloaddata

I have a UITableView with static cell that contains another UITableView which is not being updated when I call `reloadData`. Using ios5.

When I run the code below, the `subViewTable` displays the values defined in the `viewDidLoad` and does not update after the AFNetwork request.

Based on the NSLog output, cellForRowAtIndexPath is not being called after I call `reloadData` in the success block of my AFNetwork request.

My code is below

**MainViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SubViewTableViewController.h"

@interface MainController : UITableViewController{
  SubviewTableViewController *subViewTVC;
  IBOutlet UITableView *subViewTable;
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
@import "SubViewTableViewController.h"

@implementation MainController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if (subViewTableViewController == nil)
  {
    subViewTVC = [[SubViewTableViewController alloc] init];
  }
  [subViewTable setDataSource: subViewTVC];
  [subViewTable setDelegate: subViewTVC];
  subViewTableViewController.view = subViewTableViewController.tableView;
 }

@end
```

**SubViewTableController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubViewTableController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>{
  NSMutableArray *data;
}

@end
```

**SubViewTableController.m**

```
#import "SubViewTableController.h"
#import "AFNetworking.h"

@implementation SubViewTableController

- (void)fetchCustomData
{
  request = // Set NSM mutable request;
  AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest: request success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {

    // Omitted code that adds JSON objects to data array 

    [self.tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData)                                withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
  }
failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {};
  [operation start];
} 

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
  [super viewDidLoad];
  if (data == nil)
  {
    data = [NSMutuableArray arrayWithObjects:@"1",@"2", nil];
  }
  [self fetchCustomData];
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
  // Return the number of sections.
  return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
  // Return the number of rows in the section.
  NSLog(@"Data Count: %i", data.count);
  return [data count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DataCell";
  UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  // Configure the cell...
  if (cell == nil){
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }
  cell.textLabel.text = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
  NSLog(@"Cell item: %@", [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);
  return cell;
}

@end
```

**NSLog Output**

```
2012-12-16 13:59:31.538 testing[37592:f803] Data Count: 2
2012-12-16 13:59:31.539 testing[37592:f803] Cell item: 1
2012-12-16 13:59:31.541 testing[37592:f803] Cell item: 2
2012-12-16 13:59:31.575 testing[37592:f803] Data Count: 6
```

Comment: performSelectorOnMainThread is not what it seems to be, and isn't used anymore. how about `[self.tableView reloadData]` ?

Comment: i tried `[self.tableView reloadData]` and it did not update the table as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up sending a notification from my `SubView` to my `MainView` from the `success` callback of `AFJSONRequestOperation` which triggered `[subViewTable reloadData]`.

**SubViewTableController.m AFJSONRequestOperation success callback:**

```
{
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"SubViewUpdated" object:nil];
}
```

**MainViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(subViewUpdated) name:@"SubViewUpdated" object:nil];
}

- (void)subViewUpdated
{
   [subViewTable reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
  //Unregister notifications
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try fetching in a background thread...

```
-(void)updateDataInBackground {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND,0), ^(void) {
        // Background Thread:
        // hard work/updating/fetching here:

        // when finished ...
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            // Main Thread:
            [myTableView reloadData];
        }); 
    });
}
```

Comment: How would I apply that with the `AFJSONRequestOperation` from `AFNetworking`? I am calling `reloadData` in the `success` callback of my `AFJSONRequestOperation`.

Comment: you could try to put `[self fetchCustomData]` at the hard work position, and call `[self updateDataInBackground]` whenever you want to fetch.

Comment: AFNetworking already spins up a background thread when fetching a request.